# Summer and wintertime postgres timezone/timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I uploaded csv data into table in postgres. One of the columns is a character varying column with an epoch filling. The data going in is as following:

```
Example record: 1507656308.
```

The epoch character varying column is transformed to a timestamp column as follows:

```
select 
    TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + timestamp::integer * INTERVAL '1 second' as timestamp
from
    table
```

The result appeared good and I continued with it. I live in the Netherlands and here we have the winter-summertime change twice a year. Apparently my data does not differentiate.

I tried to figure out my current timezone. Which I did like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM timestamp) FROM table;
```

Resulting in:

```
3,600.0000
```

When I try to figure out my general time zone I get this:

```
show timezone
= Europe/Berlin
```

How do I get my timestamps to recognize the summer vs wintertime? Or what did I do wrong?

Comment: to support time zones/DST you should use timestamptz data type insetad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of all the creative ways to convert an epoch value (why is it stored as string?) to a `timestamp with time zone`, this is one of the more interesting one.

The simple and boring way is

```
SET timezone = 'Europe/Berlin';

SELECT to_timestamp(1507656308);

      to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2017-10-10 19:25:08+02
(1 row)
```

The time zone offset for that is two hours, because on October 10, daylight savings time was in effect (Central European Summer Time).

Indeed:

```
SELECT extract(timezone FROM to_timestamp(1507656308));

 date_part 
-----------
      7200
(1 row)
```

So everything is working as expected, right?